# Javascript Random Quote - Works, but why won't the button show up in THIS Div?

Tags: javascript, button, css-grid

I've finally got a "Random Quote" container with a functioning javascript/button.

Currently, it works in my main center section (oneSUB) but not in a different div.  I'd like to be able to move this to a different grid space like "four" in my code.  "four" is the bottom right smaller box below "oneSUB"

**The problem is the button (btnQUOTE) doesn't show up in "four"  It's possible it's just off the screen as I saw that in previous attempts at making a random quote button...but stuff was different. How/Why is the button missing in "four"?**

"four" contains and stretches for contents like paragraphs and even when below it is expanded, the button never shows up floating elsewhere, so I wouldn't think it's outside the div, but the button has seemed to behave differently there....

HTML:

```
      <div class="container-QUOTE">
        <div class="quote-text">
          <h1 id="quote"> I could eat a horse.</h1>
          <p id="author"> - whoever said</p>
        </div>
        <button id="btnQUOTE">Click Here</button>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.oneSUB {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  grid-area: one;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  max-width: 100%;
}


.four {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  grid-area: four;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#btnQUOTE {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #191716;
  color: #F15025;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


.container-QUOTE {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 180vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
  height: 55vh;
  border-left: 3px solid #f15025;
}
```

Thank you so much!  Let me know if I can provide anything else
largely basing code off this tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0poDnc5X7Zk&

JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/o2t1qya5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like its a CSS issue, here is the offending style declaration

```
.wrapper article div {
  /* height: 100%; <-- Removed this */ 
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

That seems to have handled it.

Comment: As it stands, there can only ever be one such button on the page, as the events are mounted by "document.getElementById("btnQUOTE")", which will only ever select the first button with that ID... using classes and attaching to each, would resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks!  At first still no, but I shifted that div height into the specific divs to not much avail.  You're right about removing height in .wrapper article div (though i intiailly thought i'd need it in all those divs but not currently) and I also removed height/width from the container-QUOTE and quote-text.  

Still---javascript wasn't working.  with "four" having a duplicate javascript section, it was the SECOND instance of it, so i removed the first and boom!  It fits in "four" and the javascript runs!  I'm very new at javascript but it didn't work the same when running multiple times.  !

Comment: Thank you rexfordkelly!  I believe it's pretty squared away now----didn't see your second comment.  I really appreciate the follow-through and explanation on top of helping in the first place :)

Comment: np :-) keep at it, keep using StackOverflow and keep learning... We have all been there

Comment: Also, when you feel up to it,  StackOverflow has a code-review section, which over the years I have found invaluable.